# How to call custom method in the Process (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

I want to call custom method of WinForm App using its process

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
process.Test();
```

Where is

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public void Test()
    {
      // Do something
    }
}
```

Is it possible todo?

Or let's say to call some method o fthe app if we now its process Id and so able to get the current process?

Comment: @Troopers It has no code demonstrating how to do it.

Comment: A possible solutions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication) but it 's not the only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found great solution here

Anonymous Pipes Made Easy

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087779/Anonymous-Pipes-Made-Easy